# Audio Demos on DE10 Standard not Working

Tags: audio, fpga, intel-fpga, audio-codec

I bought the [Terasic DE10 Standard](https://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=167&No=1081&PartNo=1) and am having issues trying to run the demos related to audio.

I am trying to run the two demos, DE10_Standard_Audio, and DE10_Standard_i2sound, while connecting apple headphones to line out, and 3.5 lavalier microphone to mic in, but I am not able to record anything and play it back for the 1st demo, and I don't hear anything when I speak into the microphone for the second demo either. The microphone and headphones work fine on my laptop.

DE10 Standard user manual: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/portal/dsn/42/doc-us-dsnbk-42-5505271707235-de10-standard-user-manual-sm.pdf

I am using a lavalier mic ([https://www.amazon.com/Professional-Microphone-Omnidirectional-Recording-Conference/dp/B01AG56HYQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AG56HYQ)) and connecting it to the mic-in, and then using apple earphones to line-out.

The 2 demos are Audio Recording and Playing, and Karaoke Machine as listed in the manual. I did check that some of the other demos indeed do work.

Can anyone offer any advice at all? It really seems like the demos should work? I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

I know this may be too general of a question, but I can provide any other information needed.

Thanks!!

**EDIT:**
I have tried a TS, TRS, and a TRRS type jack for the microphone input, and neither of these work unfortunately

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that I can hear when I directly breathe into the microphone, but nothing else. Unsure if this is relevant or not though.

Comment: What have you done to determine that the appropriate bitstream is loaded, and operational?

Comment: The professional mics I know generally use 48V phantom power so this isn't. But it'll require the usual electret supply voltage of up to 5V via about 5 kilohms source impedance. Does the DE10 board provide that? Check the board schematic and the Wolfson WM8731 datasheet.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The bit stream is loaded and I can tell it's operational as there is some SSD stuff that works fine.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'm taking a look at the WM8731 datasheet, and I can't quite tell, I'm really sorry. I see there is a 10k resistor connected to the micin and it goes to an opamp which seems to give it a gain of 5. I don't see anything about a supply voltage or a source impedance, but I don't know if I'm interpreting the datasheet correctly.

Could you please take a look? (https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/WM8731_v4.9.pdf)

Comment: Try loading something with the compiled-in logic analyzer component to look at the microphone signal.  Or probe if with a real scope.

Comment: There are many different types of MICs , electrodynamic, electret,... not all connections, even if they all use 3.5mm jack, are equal. You have to read both manuals and then compare if those devices are compatible.

Answer (score 2):

From the schematic in the other answer:

The phone jacks J2 (LINE IN) and J3 (LINE OUT) with L,R,NCL,NCR,and GND is a THREE ring jack (L,R,GND) and has two switch connections which probably connect to L,R with no socket present.

The Mic In jack J1 is another three ring jack with the Mic connected to L, GND (and nothing on R). It DOES connect to the MBIAS pin on the WM8371 so it is all set to power an electret mic, assuming MBIAS is correctly enabled in the chip.

The most likely problem is inserting a 4 ring jack (T R1 R2 S) with the mic connected to R2 and S, into a 3 ring T R S socket with the mic connections on T and S.

The mic is designed to work with newer jack connections (both headphone channels and mic on the same plug, as used in smartphones) while the board was designed back in the era of multimedia PCs with three jacks : phone/line out, mic in, line in.

You'll need to find or make an adapter, or source an older style mic.

Comment: So, the mic actually comes with an adapter that converts the 3 ring adapter to a 2 ring adapter. Also the person above said the WM8731 is expecting a 5 contact jack which translates to a 4 ring jack, so I'm a bit confused?

Comment: So you have an adapter already. Hope it's the right one.

Comment: I've actually been always using it, and demos still don't work. It's a 4 to 3-PIN adapter.

Comment: And where does it connect the microphone? Should only take seconds to buzz it out. Ring 2 to ... ? Sleeve to ... ?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're asking? I connect the mic to the adapter (the adapter is female TRRS to male TRS) and the adapter connects to the audio jack. I don't know what Ring 2 and Sleeve are, sorry... I'm pretty inexperienced

Comment: T is tip, R1 and R2 (or R) are rings. S is the sleeve. You need to know how the adapter is connected internally. Or make one with Sleeve to Sleeve, and R2 (mic) on socket to Tip (mic) on the plug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113086/discussion-between-lokwill-and-brian-drummond).

Answer (score 0):

The board seems to use 5 contact 3.5mm jack:

[image]

While the MIC pictures show only 4 contacts on their 3.5mm jack

[image]

Comment: Do you know it the codec requires a 5 pole connector because it has L,R,NCL,NCR,and GND? Or is it something else?

Comment: The two extra contacts are the presense switches in standard T-R-S jacks (3 contact).

Comment: I currently have a TRS jack and the demos still don't seem to play.